# What would cause edit buttons for plugins in wordpress plugins page to disappear?

Tags: wordpress

in the plugins page, under each plugins' name usually there are buttons/links like "Deactivate | Edit | Settings". Recently on one of my sites the "Edit" (and "Settings") button has disappeared. I have just "Deactivate" or "Activate | Delete".

My question is - what could cause this?

I am logged in as an administrator, so I should see the buttons. I suspect that something might have vent wrong with the installation of the last plugin but I am not sure.

Is there some scenario when these buttons get disabled (hidden) or do I have a bug / error?

**EDIT**:
This is happening on the server. I also have the exact same files (just checked with a comparer) running on my local computer, where plugins have all the buttons. I am now looking in the DB to find differences, but so far have not found anything significant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a file permissions error, make sure the user the web server is running as (typically www-data or similar) has write permissions to the plugin files.

Comment: Thanks, the site runs on *nix, I set permissions to 775 on the plugins folder and all the subfolders + files, but it doesn't seem to have helped. Or should I do something else?

Comment: I got an answer on [wordpress.stackexchange.com](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/45539/11156) that pointed to `is_writable` function, which really returns false. So I am now clarifying with the admins...

Comment: The edit buttons reappeared after giving more permissions to the files.

Answer (score 1):

Those "buttons" are called "plugin_action_links" and are/can be set by the plugin´s author.

Some plugin authors choose do not include "settings" .

If you have updated the plugin it might be that the new version does not include that ??

Does the plugin itself work ?

Is it the exact same version as on the other sites ?

As for the "edit" link - it can also be set to not appear or be disabled by third-party plugins that has to do with user-permissions or visibility of links (like adminimize for example)

example how to disable those links for plugin authors :

```
add_filter( 'plugin_action_links', 'disable_plugin_footlinks', 10, 4 );
function disable_plugin_footlinks( $actions, $plugin_file, $plugin_data, $context ) {
    // Remove edit link. if you want to remove selective use if statement
    if ( array_key_exists( 'edit', $actions ) )
        unset( $actions['edit'] );
    // Selectively remove deactivate link for specific plugins with if statement 
    if ( array_key_exists( 'deactivate', $actions ) && in_array( $plugin_file, array(
        'plugin1_specific_name_folder_/plugin1_name.php',
        'plugin2_name_folder_/plugin2_name.php'
    )))
        unset( $actions['deactivate'] );
    return $actions;
}
```

Comment: Your OP was about possible scenarios - but anyhow It does not important if it is on the server or on the local - the only thing important is if the wp installation and PLUGINS are identical on both (including the settings) - to be sure  , deactivate all the plugins - revert to the default theme - and then see if the default plugins (like askimet or hello-dolly) have the same error.

Comment: The plugin itself was also not working but I found the cause: The server is running PHP4 and the plugin had `__construct()` style constructors which are not recognized. Had to add `function ClassName() {
    $this->__construct();
}` functions to rectify this. Thanks for the support!